# Cut a part of a ring in Android Drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-xml, android-drawable

I have been trying and researching on how to cut a part of a ring in android to make it look like a percentage screen just like the image below. I have been trying to use Path, Canvas, ClipDrawable but I really can't seem to get it right. Any ideas how to implement the image below where I can cut a part of the circle to show percentage difference on the total screen?

[image]

Comment: Possible library to review: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: Thanks @MorrisonChang. It looks a bit complicated but I'll try.